# Разделение кода в контроллере

Tags: yii

Новичок в Yii Файл контроллера слишком много кода. Я хочу его разделить. Т.е некоторые операции заключить в другой фаил и подгружать его в контроллер (как include). Как в Yii это можно сделать? Спсибо

Comment: Использовать модели, а не инклюды. Смотря какой код.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в сторону actions. А вообще бизнес-логику надо выносить в модели.

Comment: мне нужно сделать отдельные файлы (как-то так) для отдельных групп пользователей

Comment: отдельные файлы, для отдельных групп - врядли, а вот экшны вы можете вынести в отельные классы CAction. Вот пример http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/170/actions-code-reuse-with-caction. Ну а разделить экшны между юзерами можно с помощью этого - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter

Comment: @zkweb, если action реализует разную логику в зависимости от входных данных, то это уже два разных action, и разнести их стоит на разные адреса.